# Eliminate shadow in legend of facet_grid using theme_classic

Tags: r, ggplot2

I wondered if it is possible to elimate the shadow in the theme_classic that appears in the boxes (legend) of facet_grid.
Theme_classic is the closest theme to APA style, which is why i prefer it. But the shadow is strange. Two lines are thicker than the other two in the box. (see figure for the boxes around 1 and 2 above)

Here is an example:

```
#library(dplyr)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(tidyverse)
library("ggsignif")    

###combining facets for sign levels.
#View(dt)


#create dataset

value <- sample(1 :50,100,replace = T)
B <- as.factor(rep(c(1,2,2,1),  50) )
C <- as.factor(rep(c(1,2),each=100) )
A <- as.factor(rep(c(4,4,3,3,2,2,1,1), 25) )

dt1 <- data.frame(A,B,C,value) %>%
  group_by(A,B,C)

ggplot(dt1, aes(x=A, y=value, fill=(B))) +theme_classic() +
  facet_wrap(vars(C))  +
  geom_boxplot(position='dodge',outlier.size=0) +geom_point(size=0.5,position=position_jitterdodge(0.2))
```

[image]

Using black and white there is now shadow for example. But other lines that i do not want.

```
ggplot(dt1, aes(x=A, y=value, fill=(B))) +theme_bw() +
  facet_wrap(vars(C))  +
  geom_boxplot(position='dodge',outlier.size=0) +geom_point(size=0.5,position=position_jitterdodge(0.2))
```

[image]

Comment: I think it might just depend on your graphics device and it is not a property of the graphic itself. Have you tried other graphic devices? e.g. ragg/cairo

Comment: I see. In the stored PDF it looks different.